# Not able to create python 3.4 environment with Anaconda3-2020.07 (conda version 4.8.4)

Tags: python, conda

I want to create a python 3.4 environment with my newly installed Anaconda 3.8 on Windows 10. The bellow command

```
conda create -n py34 python=3.4
```

will result in PackagesNotFoundError for the default channels. Adding `-c conda-forge` is also not successful. The bellow error message occurs.

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: /
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/win-64::__cuda==9.1=0

Your installed version is: 9.1
```

Can anyone suggest a solution? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have Python version 3.4 on your machine?  Was it installed by Anaconda?

Comment: @jmh No, I had to then use the older Anaconda installer to be able to create python 3.4 environment. In particular I used Anaconda3-2018.12. I think the new versions of Anaconda do not support python 3.4 anymore but don't know the way to still be able to install whichever python version one would need.

Comment: That's strange, why would CUDA be involved if the only package you're installing is Python... Try using the `free` channel (`conda create -n test-env -c free python=3.4`) ?